# JSON Table Creation

Tags: json, powerbi, power-automate

Just gonna start with saying, I sure do know how to pick a challenge (based on my skillsets or the lack of).

I'm trying to figure out how to generate a true/false style table through PowerAutomate from a PowerBI output (Exciting, right?!).

The data is a report of Active Directory users and their group memberships.  A Sample of the source data looks like this;

[image: Source data]

The desired output would look something like this;

[image: Desired Output]

How the data is being generated through PowerAutomate and PowerBI;

[image: PowerAutomate]

I'm trying to research JSON Schemas and how that all is supposed to work, but I am just really not sure where to start.  Finding an example that matches well enough to replicate into my use case is turning out to be more difficult.  Assuming this is a function JSON can complete.

I'm trying out these sites, its helping me learn but is probably not going to solve my issue;

https://odileeds.github.io/JSONSchema/
https://json-schema.org/blog/posts/applicability-json-schema-fundamentals-part-1

Any help would be very much appreciated.  Not always looking for the direct answer to the problem, if documentation exists that would push me in the right direction.

Comment: Photo's did not upload, 1 sec

Comment: Nevermind, photos are probably fine.  My company blocks Imgur for whatever reason...

Comment: If you give us the source JSON then we can probably put something together but it’s difficult without an exact example.

Comment: The “schema” is the least of your problems. The schema isn’t some magic silver bullet, it merely serves the purpose of providing you with dynamic content based on your json structure. In order for you to do what you want, you need to put the logic together.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new DAX function added recently called [`TOJSON`](https://dax.guide/tojson/) that might solve your problems, and I believe the imagined use-cases for this function includes your current challenge.

Here is what I would do:

1. Prepare your table exactly as in your desired output, in Power BI
2. Lift the **entire** query used to generate the table using [Performance Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-performance-analyzer)
3. In [DAX Studio](https://daxstudio.org/), paste the query you copied and isolate the final output table - wrap this in `TOJSON` and verify your results
4. Use this query in Power Automate - should give you the JSON response you are after directly
5. If you need to parse the JSON, you can copy the output from DAX Studio as basis for the schema in Power Automate